# Any way to search inside dmg file?

Tags: bash, mac, grep

How can I use 'grep' to search inside Mac dmg file?
I keep a 500MB password-protected disk image on laptop for tax records, sensitive data etc…Lately I've discovered that, although the command 'grep' performs as needed for searching strings anywhere else in my home dir home dir txt files, & although that image *is mounted*, I cannot get grep to search inside that dmg file. I've spent well over an hour on Terminal, researching 'man grep' & 'info grep', but no joy. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: to Spiff: I tried your suggestion 5-6x…No joy here. But thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

If the disk image is mounted, you need to tell grep to search that filesystem something like this:

```
grep -r searchtext /Volumes/diskname/
```

Note that *diskname* is conventionally **but not necessarily** the same as the filename without the `.dmg`. So double check where it got mounted under `/Volumes`.